# How to store list of strings in php/sql table

Tags: php, sql

say I have object user that has a name and a list of emails of limitless lenght. Right now I have 3 tables in my database.

```
CREATE TABLE NAME (
name TINYTEXT primary key not null
)

CREATE TABLE EMAILS (
id int primary key not null,
email varchar(30)
)

CREATE TABLE USERS (
users_name int references NAME(ID),
users_email int references EMAILS(id),
constraint pk_USERS primary key (users_name, users_email)
)
```

I feel that there is some error in the making of my tables.

And here is how I am trying to insert the name and email into my database.

```
protected function setUser($name,$email){ $stmt = $this->estabConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO USERS(users_email, users_name) VALUES (?,?)"); 

if(!$stmt->execute(array($email, $name))){ $stmt= null;        
        header('location: ../index.php?error=stmtfailed');

        exit();

    }

   

    $stmt=null;
```

The SQL statement fails

I think the problem is with the sql statment

Answer (score 0):

you must ask your self can users share an email address

- yes your design is sorrect as you have a n:m relationship ehivh i represente dby the bridge table
- no, your design is wrong and you need to show that a user can have any email adresses

The design would wlook like

```
CREATE TABLE USER(
id BIGint primary key not null,
name TINYTEXT 
)

CREATE TABLE EMAILS (
user_idBIGint primary key not null,

email varchar(30)
)
```

But normally you want only one email adress per users or maybe a second for office, so that you have a 1:! relationship which is only a part of the user table

a more extended version has not an email table but instead a table that is linked to the user(id) and where you can have many adresses with phone and location in short a 1:n relationship

For your question

> ```
> CREATE TABLE NAME (
> ID int primary key not null,
> name TINYTEXT not null
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE EMAILS (
> id int primary key not null,
> email varchar(30)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE USERS (
> users_name int references NAME(ID),
> users_email int references EMAILS(id),
> constraint pk_USERS primary key (users_name, users_email)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO USERS(users_name,users_email) VALUES (1,1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM USERS
> ```
>
> ```
> users_name | users_email
> ---------: | ----------:
>          1 |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f7ffb56756aa67f4a1ea9a429444880)*

To get that to work i changed your design, to corresond with your brisge table.

so as long as you don't enter the actual anme and email adress every should work

Comment: thank you @nbk. In my case, the users can share emails. What I am trying to do is when I set a user, it adds the name to the user table and email to its corresponding list for that user/name in the emails table. I see that my design is correct but my statement is failing when I am inserting it. Can you see any errors in my statement or tables? thanks sm!

Comment: what are you using mysqli or pdo?

Comment: i am using PDO.

Comment: i added some more thoughts, as your code php work just fine, but i don't know what you actually are inerting, but the design has to be changed

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot! I will be inserting strings.

Comment: If I wanted to insert this INSERT INTO USERS(users_name,users_email) VALUES (mike, mikey@gmail.com)  would I do this,  CREATE TABLE NAME (
ID int primary key not null,
name TINYTEXT not null
);

CREATE TABLE EMAILS (
id int primary key not null,
email varchar(30)
);

CREATE TABLE USERS (
users_name TINYTEXT references NAME(name),
users_email varchar(30) references EMAILS(email),
constraint pk_USERS primary key (users_name, users_email)
);   @nbk

Comment: Also I want to enter the actual name and email not numbers @nbk

Comment: in your code both columns are int not varchar and also you need a INSERT Trigger that takes but inputed data automatically in the other tables, but you need to extend your datamdel, the more you tell me the more i thoing you should take a step back and think what you want to do